# WSO2 Mobile Version for store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-iot

I was exploring the store of WSO2 AppManager through my device, but it was redirecting to the web version of it.Is there any mobile version which we can access for the store.Any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently(with EMM 2.0.1), there is no mobile catalog application available for browsing the app store and installing apps on to your device, like the Google playstore. However with EMM 2.1.0 which is the upcoming version of WSO2 EMM, there will be a Catalog application available for Android platform.

https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/tree/master/modules/mobile-agents/android/app-catalog

Comment: ok , thanks,most probably when will the new version  be available.